# SQL While Loop takes way too long

Tags: sql

After days of searching the internet for an answer and trying to improve this myself I have finally decided to ask for help.

I receive a flat file each day from a client that contains about 1.1 million rows of data. I import this data into a staging database with SSIS (SQL Server 2012). This takes only a few seconds. The data is basically appointment information.

There are several fields in the flat file but the ones I have to use to synchronize the reporting table are called:

UpdateType - contains either INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE.
ChangeDate - Date time-stamp of when the row changed.
UniqueKey - UniqueKey + ChangeDate create a unique key for the row

The requirements from the client are that I either INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE the row from the reporting database in the order of the ChangeDate by UniqueKey. I could not figure out how to do this in a set so I created a while loop which takes over 20 hours to run which is way too long.

Here is an example of the flat file data I receive:

```
UpdateType   UniqueKey   ChangeDate              MoreDate
INSERT       27244595    2013-09-24 08:51:48.367 synchronize data follows
DELETE       27244595    2013-09-25 10:15:08.433 synchronize data follows
INSERT       27244595    2013-09-25 10:15:09.990 synchronize data follows
DELETE       27244595    2013-09-25 15:02:36.287 synchronize data follows
INSERT       27244595    2013-09-25 15:02:36.610 synchronize data follows
```

As you can see the same record was inserted then deleted many times but this isn't always the case. In this example data, only the last record should appear in the reporting database table, 1 appointment is scheduled.

Here is another example from the same flat file:

```
UpdateType   UniqueKey   ChangeDate              MoreDate
INSERT       28243572    2013-09-25 10:15:08.610 synchronize data follows
INSERT       28243572    2013-09-25 10:15:09.880 synchronize data follows
DELETE       28243572    2013-09-25 14:01:36.210 synchronize data follows
INSERT       28243572    2013-09-25 14:02:37.287 synchronize data follows
```

In this example the first and last record should appear in the reporting database table. There are 2 appointments scheduled. There are other times when an update in in the mix.

I don't create the reports and have no idea what they look like.

Here is the code I wrote to synchronize the reporting database from the staging database. If you have any suggestions on how to improve this process I welcome them and appreciate the help.

```
DECLARE --DECLARE SOME VARIABLES TO USE IN THE LOOP
 @UPDATETYPE VARCHAR(6) --THIS WILL BE INSERT, DELETE OR UPDATE
,@KEY INTEGER --THIS IS THE UNIQUEKEY
,@CHANGEDATE DATETIME --THIS IS THE CHANGE DATE FROM THE FLATFILE

--START A WHILE LOOP TO GO ROW BY ROW 
WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STAGEDB.DBO.APPIONTMENTCHANGE) > 0
    BEGIN

SELECT @UPDATETYPE = (SELECT TOP 1 [UPDATETYPE] FROM STAGEDB.DBO.APPIONTMENTCHANGE 
            ORDER BY [UNIQUEKEY], [CHANGEDATE]) --GET THE UPDATE TYPE FOR THE IF STATEMENTS

SELECT @KEY = (SELECT TOP 1 [UNIQUEKEY] FROM STAGEDB.DBO.APPIONTMENTCHANGE 
         ORDER BY [UNIQUEKEY], [CHANGEDATE]) --GET THE KEY

SELECT @CHANGEDATE = (SELECT TOP 1 [CHANGEDATE] FROM STAGEDB.DBO.APPIONTMENTCHANGE 
            ORDER BY [UNIQUEKEY], [CHANGEDATE]) --GET THE CHANGEDATE

--IF THIS ROW IS AN INSERT THEN COMPLETE THIS ON THE REPORT DATABASE
IF @UPDATETYPE = 'INSERT'
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO [REPORTDB].[DBO].[APPOINTMENT]
            ([REPORTDB].[DBO].[APPOINTMENT].[UNIQUEKEY]
            ,[REPORTDB].[DBO].[APPOINTMENT].[APPOINTMENT]
            ,[REPORTDB].[DBO].[APPOINTMENT].[CLIENTLEADBK]
            ,[REPORTDB].[DBO].[APPOINTMENT].[FIRSTNAME]
            ,[REPORTDB].[DBO].[APPOINTMENT].[LASTNAME]
            ,[REPORTDB].[DBO].[APPOINTMENT].[PHONENUMBER]
            ,[REPORTDB].[DBO].[APPOINTMENT].[PHONENUMBER2]
            ,[REPORTDB].[DBO].[APPOINTMENT].[PHONENUMBER3]
            ,[REPORTDB].[DBO].[APPOINTMENT].[PHONENUMBER4]
            ,[REPORTDB].[DBO].[APPOINTMENT].[ADDRESSSTREET]
            ,[REPORTDB].[DBO].[APPOINTMENT].[ADDRESSCITY]
            ,[REPORTDB].[DBO].[APPOINTMENT].[ADDRESSSTATE]
            ,[REPORTDB].[DBO].[APPOINTMENT].[ADDRESSZIP]
            ,[REPORTDB].[DBO].[APPOINTMENT].[ADDRESSCOUNTRY])
SELECT TOP 1 [UNIQUEKEY]
            ,[APPOINTMENT]
            ,[CLIENTLEADBK]
            ,[FIRSTNAME]
            ,[LASTNAME]
            ,[PHONENUMBER]
            ,[PHONENUMBER2]
            ,[PHONENUMBER3]
            ,[PHONENUMBER4]
            ,[ADDRESSSTREET]
            ,[ADDRESSCITY]
            ,[ADDRESSSTATE]
            ,[ADDRESSZIP]
            ,[ADDRESSCOUNTRY]
        FROM [STAGEDB].[DBO].[APPIONTMENTCHANGE] 
    ORDER BY [UNIQUEKEY], [CHANGEDATE];

--ONCE THE INSERT IS COMPLETED THEN DELETE THE ALREADY WORKED RECORD FROM THE STAGING DATABASE
DELETE FROM [STAGEDB].[DBO].[APPIONTMENTCHANGE] 
WHERE [UNIQUEKEY] = @KEY AND [CHANGEDATE] = @CHANGEDATE;

END

--IF THE ROW IS A DELETE REQUEST THEN COMPLETE THIS ON THE REPORT DATABASE
IF @UPDATETYPE = 'DELETE'
BEGIN

DELETE FROM [REPORTDB].[DBO].[APPOINTMENT]
WHERE [UNIQUEKEY] = @KEY AND [CHANGEDATE] = @CHANGEDATE;

--ONCE THE DELETE IS COMPLETED THEN DELETE THE ALREADY WORKED RECORD FROM THE STAGING DATABASE
DELETE FROM [STAGEDB].[DBO].[APPIONTMENTCHANGE] 
WHERE [UNIQUEKEY] = @KEY AND [CHANGEDATE] = @CHANGEDATE;

END

--IF THE ROW IS A UPDATE REQUEST DO THAT
IF @UPDATETYPE = 'UPDATE'
BEGIN

    UPDATE [REPORTDB].[DBO].[APPOINTMENT]
       SET [REPORTDB].[DBO].[APPOINTMENT].[APPOINTMENT] = B.[APPOINTMENT]
      ,[REPORTDB].[DBO].[APPOINTMENT].[CLIENTLEADBK] = B.[CLIENTLEADBK]
      ,[REPORTDB].[DBO].[APPOINTMENT].[FIRSTNAME] = B.[FIRSTNAME]
      ,[REPORTDB].[DBO].[APPOINTMENT].[LASTNAME] = B.[LASTNAME]
      ,[REPORTDB].[DBO].[APPOINTMENT].[PHONENUMBER] = B.[PHONENUMBER]
      ,[REPORTDB].[DBO].[APPOINTMENT].[PHONENUMBER2] = B.[PHONENUMBER2]
      ,[REPORTDB].[DBO].[APPOINTMENT].[PHONENUMBER3] = B.[PHONENUMBER3]
      ,[REPORTDB].[DBO].[APPOINTMENT].[PHONENUMBER4] = B.[PHONENUMBER4]
      ,[REPORTDB].[DBO].[APPOINTMENT].[ADDRESSSTREET] = B.[ADDRESSSTREET]
      ,[REPORTDB].[DBO].[APPOINTMENT].[ADDRESSCITY] = B.[ADDRESSCITY]
      ,[REPORTDB].[DBO].[APPOINTMENT].[ADDRESSSTATE] = B.[ADDRESSSTATE]
      ,[REPORTDB].[DBO].[APPOINTMENT].[ADDRESSZIP] = B.[ADDRESSZIP]
      ,[REPORTDB].[DBO].[APPOINTMENT].[ADDRESSCOUNTRY] = B.[ADDRESSCOUNTRY]
      FROM [REPORTDB].[DBO].[APPOINTMENT]
INNER JOIN [STAGEDB].[DBO].[APPIONTMENTCHANGE] B 
        ON [REPORTDB].[DBO].[APPOINTMENT].[UNIQUEKEY] = B.[UNIQUEKEY]
     WHERE [REPORTDB].[DBO].[APPOINTMENT].[UNIQUEKEY] = @KEY;

--ONCE THE UPDATE IS COMPLETED THEN DELETE THE ALREADY WORKED RECORD FROM THE STAGING DATABASE
DELETE FROM [STAGEDB].[DBO].[APPIONTMENTCHANGE] 
WHERE [UNIQUEKEY] = @KEY AND [CHANGEDATE] = @CHANGEDATE;
END
    END
```

I would much rather have all the files that need inserted, all that need deleted and all that should be updated not every record change that occurred but this is what I have to work with right now.

All serious ideas for improvements are appreciated. Please provide as much explanation as you can.

Comment: The problem here is the ordering requirement "*The requirements .. are [to] INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE .. in the* order *of the ContactDate by UniqueKey.*"  Why do you need to duplicate all of this SQL activity?  If the last action on a UniqueKey is DELETE, why can't you just do that and skip all of the preceeding steps?

Comment: The problem with just doing the last step is the second example, only 1 record would be added when there should be 2.

Comment: Not according to your script it wouldn't. The `DELETE` would either delete both or neither because there's no `[CHANGEDATE]` being set in the table. In fact, the more I look at the script, the more it seems like the entire handling of CHANGEDATE is wrong and completely contrary to your description. What's really going on here?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that the table is about 44 columns wide and I deleted a crap load of columns in the posted code because I didn't think it was needed to get the idea of what I was doing. If you look at the delete code you will see it uses the changedate column

Comment: That's fine, but the handling of ContactDate/[CHANGEDATE] is very important and we need to see that correctly in order to understand what is really going on here. As it currently stands there is no way to rectify your description of ordering the actions with the method of those actions identifying specific records. `UniqueKey+ContactDate/[CHANGEDATE]` cannot be the primary key of both the change table and the target table, and still have multiple ordered actions on the same target row. Please edit your post to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

Use normal sql commands.  First the insert

```
insert into realtable
(field1, field2, etc)
select field1, field2, etc
from stagingtable
where idfield in
(select idfield 
from stagingtable
except 
select idfield
from realtable)
```

updates

```
update r
set field1 = s.field1
, etc
from realtable r join stagingtable s on something
where whatever
```

deletions

```
delete from reatable
where idfield in
(select idfield
from staging table
where you want the record deleted from the real table)
```

Comment: This is actually how I was performing the task initially. The Problem was that it was either completely deleting records that should have been there or inserting duplicates because the way that every single SQL process is being recorded. I actually asked to just get records to insert, update and delete without all the middle processes and was told no.

Comment: That means you had the right idea but made mistakes with the details.  It's still the best approach.